# PHPStan "Call to an undefined method" errors with symfony/phpunit-bridge

Tags: symfony, phpunit, phpstan

PHPStan analysis combined with `symfony/phpunit-bridge` raises `Call to an undefined method` errors.

[image]

Is it possible to ignore these errors with simple PHPStan configuration?

Comment: If someone get stuck on this one as I did, try installing `symfony/test-pack`.